# Javascript Animate won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the width or right position, but neither are working.

This is what I've included in my HTML file (I have Jquery linked):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slide").click(function(){
        $('#contact-wrap').animate({
            right: '0'
        }, 500);    
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

I have an anchor's id set to "slide" and I want the `div` named "contact-wrap" to change from its negative right value to 0. I'm guessing that my JS code is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried removing the quotes around `'0'`?

Comment: Please set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo. It would make things much easier for us.

Comment: Can you please include your HTML and CSS ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested your javascript and it looks alright and slides the div accordingly. My test html, css and jscript are:

css:

```
#contact-wrap 
{     
    height: 30px; 
    width:10px;
    border:solid 1px black; 
    display: block;
    position:absolute;right:-200px;
}
```

html:

```
<a id="slide">test</a>
<div id="contact-wrap"></div>
```

javascript:

```
$("#slide").click(function(){             
    $('#contact-wrap').animate(
        { right: '0' }, 
        500);             
});
```

Comment: I have a demo of your code -> http://jsfiddle.net/snWHs/ I updated the `right` css value so you can see the actual move ... but like you said ... working fine ... i guess the initial CSS of the OP is the problem